# Counting the number of records with lambda expression

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have an ASP.NET MVC4 project with Entity Framework.

How to **count** (with a lambda expression) the number of Request where the related MaterialPackingID = 123 ?

Here are my classes:

```
public class Request
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int RequestID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TransportedMaterial> TransportedMaterials { get; set; }
}

public class TransportedMaterial
{
    [Key]
    public int TransportedMaterialID { get; set; }                
    public MaterialPacking MaterialPacking { get; set; }
}


public class MaterialPacking
{
    public int MaterialPackingID { get; set; }
    public string DescriptionFr { get; set; }
    public string DescriptionNl { get; set; }
}
```

So:

- 1 Request may contain several TransportedMaterial
- 1 TransportedMaterial contains 1 MaterialPacking

Here is what I try:

```
    public int CountExistingRequestsFilterByMaterialPacking(int id)
    {
        using (var unitOfWork = UnitOfWorkFactory.Create())
        {
            var requestRepository = unitOfWork.Create<Request>();
            var materialPackingRepository = unitOfWork.Create<MaterialPacking>();
            var materialPacking = materialPackingRepository.SingleOrDefault(x => x.MaterialPackingID == id);

            if (materialPacking == null)
                throw new FaultException("Packing not found");

            return requestRepository.GetAll().Where(x => x..... == materialPacking.MaterialPackingID).Count();
        }
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: in what way does what you've tried not work?

Comment: You can use `Count(expression)` method to count. Doesn't it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does something like this work?

```
return requestRepository.GetAll().Count(req => 
    req.TransportedMaterials.Any(tm => 
        tm.MaterialPacking.MaterialPackingID == materialPacking.MaterialPackingID)
    );
```

Assumptions: you want a count of requests that contain one or more TransportedMaterial objects having a MaterialPackingID matching the one you are interested in.